# Making file downloadable with Firebase: unexpected token in firebase.json

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have been trying to edit my `firebase.json` to make a file available for download. I know I can do this with `Content-Type: data/octet-stream` but whenever I do `firebase deploy`, I get:

```
$ firebase deploy

Error: There was an error loading firebase.json:

Unexpected token 'h' at 10:4
  "headers": [ {
   ^
File: "/home/barend/Projects/firebase/firebase.json"
```

This is my firebase.json:

```
{
  "firebase": "xxx",
  "public": "public",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "**/*.pyc"
  ]
  "headers": [ {
  "source" : "**/*.py",
  "headers" : [ {
  "key" : "Content-Type",
  "value" : "data/octet-stream"
} ]
}
```

How can I fix this?

---

**Update**: after carefully reading Frank's comment, I realized he meant 'comma', and not 'command' (stupid me). I changed what he pointed out was wrong, and I got another error:

```
Error: hosting.headers[0] requires property "headers"
```

This one was easy to fix. I had to change `headers` to `Headers` and then it worked fine. For future readers, this is the fixed code:

```
{
  "firebase": "xxx",
  "public": "public",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "**/*.pyc"
  ],
  "Headers": [ {
    "source" : "**/*.py",
    "key" : "Content-Type",
    "value" : "data/octet-stream"
   } ]
}
```

Then it worked fine.

Comment: You're missing a command after the first `]`. Note that there are great online JSON validators (such as http://jsonlint.com/) that can help you find typos such as this one. You've also nested `headers` inside of that `headers` array, which won't work.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks! that fixed it. Feel free to post it as an answer :)

Comment: Good to hear that it got you sorted. Typos of this sort are unlikely to help others (since they won't be looking for a typo), so I voted to close instead.